# kotlin data sharing between activity and view model

Tags: android, kotlin, authentication, environment-variables, android-context

I've recently started teaching myself kotlin and am building an App to get to grips with application fundamentals.. so appologies if the answer is out there somewhere but I couldn't find a relevant solution.

I have a `LoginActivity.kt` that sets up a `LoginViewModel` that contains a live mutable variable for the login result like so

```
class LoginViewModel(private val loginRepository: LoginRepository) : ViewModel() {

    private val _loginForm = MutableLiveData<LoginFormState>()
    val loginFormState: LiveData<LoginFormState> = _loginForm

    private val _loginResult = MutableLiveData<LoginResult>()
    val loginResult: MutableLiveData<LoginResult> = _loginResult

    fun login(email: String, password: String) {

        runBlocking {
            // do login
        }
    }


    fun loginDataChanged(username: String, password: String) {
         // validate login fields
    }

    private fun isUserNameValid(username: String): Boolean {
         // validate username fields

    }

    // A placeholder password validation check
    private fun isPasswordValid(password: String): Boolean {
         // validate passwordfields
    }
}
```

This all works fine so far with the ViewModel, by way of the Model and View, communicate with the server I've set up thereby authenticating the user login credentials.

On a successful login I run

```
    private fun updateUiWithUser(loggedInUser: LoggedInUser) {
        startActivity(
                Intent(
                        this@LoginActivity,
                        MainActivity::class.java
                ).putExtra("loggedInUser", loggedInUser)
        )
    }
```

which sets up the main activity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var loggedInUser : LoggedInUser // ? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        loggedInUser = intent.getParcelableExtra("loggedInUser")!!
        Log.v("Main auth token", loggedInUser.token)

        val navView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)

        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_dashboard, R.id.navigation_notifications
            )
        )

        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }

}
```

this all works so far and on a success login the the Log displays that the loggedInUser variable is set

I would then like to access the logged in users authentication token from a view that will perform authenticated communication with the server EXCEPT I can't figure out a way to do so :/

My thought was that I would be able to do something like `MainActivity().loggedInUser.token` in the retrofit factory like so

```
    fun getAuthorizedRetrofit(): Retrofit {

        val authorizationToken = MainActivity().loggedInUser.token

        Log.v("retro builder auth", authorizationToken)

        val client: OkHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(object : Interceptor {
            @Throws(IOException::class)
            override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
                val newRequest: Request = chain.request().newBuilder()
                        .addHeader("Authorization", "Token ${authorizationToken}")
                        .build()
                return chain.proceed(newRequest)
            }
        }).build()

        return Retrofit.Builder()
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl(API.BASE_URL)
                .build()
    }
```

but of course at this point it is trying to instantiate a new `MainActivity` so there is no initiated logged in user.

I feel like I am missing some fundamental way of accessing the login authentication data from my login repository but to my knowledge this is lost once it is not required in context any more?

Am I missing some key understanding of how classes are instantiated, handled and accessed or is there just an error with my approach? If the latter, how do I make the user authentication credentials available to any view that might want to communicate with the server?

The server is all set up in django with postgresql database and all the api call works from the app with hard coded authenication credentials but obviously this is not a working solution.

I've tried to be verbose for future googlers but if something needs to be clearer please comment :)

Comment: Hi, interesting, perhaps use an auth library or maybe save the information in the current session or application... hmm

Comment: Where is this function called from? Why can't you make the necessary token a parameter of this function?

Comment: @IronMan Isn't saving the information a security risk? Probably not as much as saving the username and password but still. Can you recommend an auth library with possible some sample code to see how the credentials would be stored in the login ViewModel and then accessed from an unrelated ViewModel

Comment: @Tenfour04 The authorized retrofit builder is used in any ViewModel related to commincating with the server. Of course passing the authenication token everywhere is possible but it seems unweildy and difficult to maintain

Comment: The current recommendation from Google is to have a single Activity for your whole application, so you could put it in a ViewModel that is scoped to that Activity and it will be available to any Fragment.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I really am building knowledge of kotlin from the ground up so while I'm sure you're right your comment is a bit too fast. 

My `LoginActivity` has a `ViewModel` with `MutableLiveData` fields that could potentially be what you're referring to but as stated in the comment I start my `MainActivity` after a successful login.

a) Is `LoginActivity` still active after `updateUIWithUser`?
b) Does that mean I contradict best practices by having both `MainActivity` and `LoginActivity`?
c) How can I access the `ViewModel` of `LoginActivity` from a fragment managed by `MainActivity`?

Comment: Separate Activities are totally walled off from one another. To share data between them, you pass them in the "extras" Bundle of the Intent that you use to start the second Activity, and then in the second Activity, you can read the values back out. If your data is not made up of primitives, Strings, or a collection of Strings, then you need to make your data class Parcelable. IMO, it is OK to have a separate Activity for logging in since that is so distinct from all the content that comes after a user is logged in.

Comment: Yes so I have figured out this much about passing data between activities, my LoggedInUser data class is parcelable and is read correctly when `MainActivity` starts. Are you saying that creating a `ViewModel` for `MainActivity` and storing the `LoggedInUser` there will make it accessible anywhere? How can I access the `ViewModel` of `MainActivity` from a function being run from a fragment?